# Loading Grass 7.0 vectors in QGIS broken?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins

Running QGis 2.8.1 in Win7 (64bits), installed through OSGEO4W.
When trying to load a Grass 7.0 vector file in QGis, the program will simply crash without any notice. I can load old Grass vectors though. Is this happening with anyone else? I could not find any posts about problems with loading grass 7.0 vectors

Answer (score 2):

In an email exchange with Radim Blazek in the grass-user mailing list he explained:

> QGis from OSGeo4Win is compiled with GRASS 6, you cannot get it
> working with GRASS 7. Reinstalling will not help. The provider and the
> plugin has first to be fixed to support build with both GRASS 6 and
> GRASS 7.  This is in the first package of proposed upgrade:
> http://www.gissula.eu/qgis-grass-plugin-crowdfunding/
>
> Then a bat to start QGIS with GRASS 7 could be added also to OSGeo4Win.

So, spreading the word: Radim launched a crowdfunding campaign to support the GRASS
plugin upgrade. If you'd like to contribute, the address is http://www.gissula.eu/qgis-grass-plugin-crowdfunding/

Answer (score 1):

Note that GRASS GIS 7 comes with an updated vector format (esp. new spatial index). In order to use older vector data (from GRASS GIS 6) in GRASS GIS 7 the user has to rebuild the topology. Additionally it is recommended to switch the database backend from DBF files to SQLite. Both can be done in an automated way per MAPSET as described in this wiki page:

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Convert_all_GRASS_6_vector_maps_to_GRASS_7

Comment: Markus, all my vectors where created inside GRASS7 so they are in the correct format. I just wanted to pen them in QGis to create some figures using QGis Composer.

Comment: Perhaps your GRASS GIS installation was not compiled with large file support? I have no other explanation...

Comment: So I take this is happening only to me? It's not something that is affecting other OsGeo4W users?